# I there a way to add overflow-x: hidden to html and body without affecting Javascript scrolling event?

Tags: javascript, css, overflow, mobile-safari, horizontal-scrolling

I am trying to prevent axis-scrolling for the whole page, I used overflow-x: hidden on html but iPhone and iPad IOS 12 and newer on safari and chrome ignored it. After, I put overflow-x: hidden on both html and body that recognized on both devices but my Javascript scrolling event stopped from getting executed. I already tried to wrap all elements in div containers and add overflow-x: hidden but still not fixed. Please Help I gave up.

that fixed overflow-x on iPhone and iPad but Javascript scroll event stopped from getting executed.

```
html{
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  overflow-x: hidden;
 }

body{
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    height: 100vh;
    background: linear-gradient(to top right, violet, cyan, darkviolet);
    width: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
   }

   .wrapper{

     width: 100%;
     height: auto;
   }
```

it works fine on all devices except iPhone and iPad IOS 12 and newer on Safari and Chrome

CSS

```
html{
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  overflow-x: hidden;
 }

body{
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    height: 100vh;
    background: linear-gradient(to top right, violet, cyan, darkviolet);
    width: 100%;
   /* overflow-x: hidden; */ Removed
   }

   .wrapper{

     width: 100%;
     height: auto;
   }

JavaScript

window.addEventListener('scroll', ()=>{

      navScroll();
      aboutFade();
      contactAnime();

        if (window.scrollY > 235) {
            navBar.style.background = '#fff';
            navBar.style.height = '70px';
            navBar.classList.add('nav-bar-shadow-anime');
            navBar.style.transition = '1s';
            for(var i = 0; i < navBarA.length; i++){
                navBarA[i].style.color = "black";
                navBarA[i].style.transition = "1s";
            }
            navBarMobile.style.color = "black";
        }
        else {
            navBar.style.background = 'transparent';
            navBar.style.height = '100px';
            navBar.classList.remove('nav-bar-shadow-anime');
            navBar.style.transition = '1s';
            for(var i = 0; i < navBarA.length; i++){
                navBarA[i].style.color = "white";
                navBarA[i].style.transition = "1s";
            }
            navBarMobile.style.color = "white";
        }

        if(window.scrollY > 800){
            for(var i = 0; i < percentBar.length; i++){
                experienceMeter[i].style.width = percentBar[i].getAttribute('data-target');
                experienceMeter[i].style.transition = "3s";
                experienceMeter[i].style.transitionDelay = "1s";
            }
        }

        if(window.scrollY > 1400){
            /*
            projectOne.style.left = "0";
            projectOne.style.transition = '2s';
            projectOne.classList.add('project-img-anime');

            projectThree.style.left = "0";
            projectThree.style.transition = '2s';
            projectThree.classList.add('project-img-anime');
            */

            projectOne.style.top = "0";
            projectOne.style.opacity = "1";
            projectOne.style.transition = "0.2s";
            projectOne.style.transitionDelay = "1s";

            projectTwo.style.top = "0";
            projectTwo.style.opacity = "1";
            projectTwo.style.transition = "0.2s";
            projectTwo.style.transitionDelay = "1.5s";

            projectThree.style.top = "0";
            projectThree.style.opacity = "1";
            projectThree.style.transition = "0.2s";
            projectThree.style.transitionDelay = "2s";

            projectFour.style.top = "0";
            projectFour.style.opacity = "1";
            projectFour.style.transition = "0.2s";
            projectFour.style.transitionDelay = "2.5s";

            projectFive.style.top = "0";
            projectFive.style.opacity = "1";
            projectFive.style.transition = "0.2s";
            projectFive.style.transitionDelay = "3s";

            projectSix.style.top = "0";
            projectSix.style.opacity = "1";
            projectSix.style.transition = "0.2s";
            projectSix.style.transitionDelay = "3.5s";
        }
        else {
            /*
            projectOne.style.left = "-160%";
            projectOne.style.transition = '2s';
            */
        }

    },false);
```

expected to prevent axis-scrolling on all devices without scroll event error.

Comment: Better to use a library and read the directions on how to use it. https://github.com/locomotivemtl/locomotive-scroll

Comment: I actually fixed it by removing CSS body height: 100vh; without using library but I will keep those info in mind if I want to use it in the future. Thanks for the info.